# Sort by two columns on mx DataGrid

Tags: apache-flex, collections, datagrid

I have a DataGrid that I'd like to have two sorts applied to it. Currently there are three columns.

Name | Type | Date

When the user clicks on the header type column it is sorted correctly by Name as well. Type > Name.

If they click the name header I would like it to sort normally (not two columns).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [sortCompareFunction](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/dataGridClasses/DataGridColumn.html#sortCompareFunction) on the DataGridColumn.